# DragEnd event on Google Maps Marker

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to fire an event on mouse-drag-end (or any event) associated to google-map-marker using Polymer, but nothing fires.

```
<google-map latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}">
    <google-map-marker latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" 
        on-google-map-marker-mouseup="markerMoved" 
        draggable="true" mouse-events="true">
    </google-map-marker>
</google-map>

Polymer({
    markerMoved: function(event) { ... }
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This works for me: http://jsbin.com/hizonevoyi/edit?html,output

Comment: Did you try it with `console.log('fired')` just to make sure it's doing _something_? If not, try that now; if so, it'd be nice to change the code to be that, just so we can copypasta easily.